# MySQL Conditional GROUP_BY

Tags: mysql

My database looks (a bit) like this:

```
Table 'posts':
ID  title             text
62  Trees in Europe   You can find fine trees in european woods.
63  Animals in Europe The european fauna is mostly harmless.

Table 'translations':
ID  reference_id  reference_field  translation
36  62            title            Bäume in Europa
37  62            text             Da sind viele Bäume in Europas Wäldern .
44  63            text             Die meisten europäischen Tiere sind harmlos.
47  63            title            Tiere in Europa
```

The `reference_field` in the `translations`-table gives the information for which field of the `posts`-table the translated text will stand.

I would like to have a SELECT with one row as result that gives me a concatenation of the corresponding textes, that is

```
ID  title                                  text
62  Trees in Europe // Bäume in Europa     You can find fine trees in european woods. // Du kannst in Europas Wäldern viele Bäume finden.
63  Animals in Europe // Tiere in Europa   The european fauna is mostly harmless. // Die meisten europäischen Tiere sind harmlos.
```

I tried quite a bit, but couldn't get it. The problem I have is that the reference of the `translation` column changes in each row. The closest I get is that *one* of the columns is concatenated correctly:

```
SELECT a.id, 
IF (t.reference_field LIKE "title", CONCAT(left(a.title,20), ' // ', LEFT(t.value, 20)), LEFT(a.title, 20)) AS title, 
IF (t.reference_field LIKE "text", CONCAT(left(a.text,20), ' // ', LEFT(t.value, 20)), LEFT(a.text, 20)) AS summary, 
t.reference_field
FROM posts AS a 
JOIN translations AS t on a.id = t.reference_id 
WHERE a.id=62 
AND t.reference_field IN ('introtext', 'title') 
GROUP BY a.id;
```

How do I have to modify the SQL so that the expected result is given?

Any help or hints are appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest the following:

```
SELECT p.ID
    ,concat(p.title, ' // ', t_title.translation) AS title
    ,concat(p.text, ' // ', t_text.translation) AS text
FROM posts AS p
LEFT JOIN translations AS t_title ON p.id = t_title.reference_id
    AND t_title.reference_field = 'title'
LEFT JOIN translations AS t_text ON p.id = t_text.reference_id
    AND t_text.reference_field = 'text'
```

SQL Fiddle Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5ad47d/4/0

a Little Explanation: when you have the same reference_id multiple times and you are joining These 2 tables then you will get more rows then you expect. so it is necessary to filter. that's why I used the reference_field and joined 2x time

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I was in need of the conceptual idea, not the correct syntax. I had to insert the CONCAT()-function - that didn't hurt.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I fixed the answer and added a working SQL Fiddle demo